# Laravel 5 new auth: Get current user and how to implement roles?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-5

I am currently experimenting with the new Laravel 5 and got the authentication to work (register/login).

To get the authenticated user in my controller I currently inject `Guard` into the controller action:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class ClientController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(Guard $auth)
    {
        return view('client.index', ['user' => $auth->user()]);
    }
...
```

**First Question:** Is this the recommended way?

**Second Question:** How would I go about implementing some kind of roles/permissions? Something like `client.edit`, `client.add`, ... Does Larval 5 offer some kind of convenience here? 
How would I set the necessary role/permission for a route/controller action?

I am thinking that I might need to write my own middleware for that. Any suggestions on how to approach the problem?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

After spending some more time on Laravel 5 I can an answer my own question:

**Is injecting `Guard` the recommended way?** No: If you need to access `Auth` in your view, you can do so already like this:

```
@if( Auth::check() )
    Current user: {{ Auth::user()->name }}
@endif
```

This uses the `Auth` facade. A list of all available facades is in `config/app.php` under `aliases:`

**What if I need `Auth` in my controller?** Injecting an instance of `Guard` like shown in the question works, but you don't need to. You can use the `Auth` facade like we did in the template:

```
    public function index()
    {
        if(\Auth::check() && \Auth::user()->name === 'Don') {
            // Do something
        }
        return view('client.index');
    }
```

Be aware that the `\` is needed before the facade name since L5 is using namespaces.

**I want to have permissions/roles using the new auth mechanism in L5:** I implemented a lightweight permission module using the new middleware, it is called **Laraguard**. Check it out on Github and let me know what you think: https://github.com/cgrossde/Laraguard

**UPDATE:** For the sake of completeness I want to mention two more projects. They  provide everything you need to save roles and permissions in the DB and work perfectly together with Laraguard or on their own:

- https://github.com/caffeinated/shinobi
- https://github.com/romanbican/roles

Comment: did you create filter routes for user role base i am stuck with https://github.com/romanbican/roles

Comment: Anyway to do it without the facade?

Answer (score 0):

If you want make your own custom authentification, you need to keep the User model from Laravel 5 with all the dependency. After you will be able to login your user in your controller. Dont forget to put (use Auth;) after the namespace of your controller.